# Can someone give me an example of admissible heuristic that is not consistent?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, heuristics

In this figure:

[image]
let's assume that h(C)=1
If f(A)=g(A)+h(A)=0+4=4, and f(C)=g(C)+h(C)=1+1=2
Then f(C) is NOT greater than or equal to f(A)
Therefore this example is consistent and admissible, but can someone give me an example of admissible heuristic that is not consistent? please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consistent and Admissible Heuristics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516027/consistent-and-admissible-heuristics)

Comment: isn't your example heuristics admissible? it never overestimates the real cost. `4 = h(A) <= real cost from A to G = 4` ,`1 = h(C) <= real cost from C to G = 3`

Comment: @svs yes you are right, my mistake.

Comment: But again since `f(A) > f(C)` your example heuristics is not consistent. Then your heuristics `h(A)=4, h(C)=1, h(G)=0` is admissible and not consistent - exactly what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

- [Admissibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic#Formulation)

if you want your heuristics to be admissible  then you should have that `h(n) <=h*(n)` for every node `n` where `h*` is the real cost to the goal. In your case you want:

```
h(A) <= 4
h(C) <= 3
h(G) <= 0
```

- [Consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic)

If you want your heuristics to be consistent then you should have that `h(G) = 0` and `h(n) <= cost(n, c) + h(c)` where the node `c` is a child of node `c`. So in your case

```
h(A) <= 1 + h(C)
h(C) <= 3 + h(G) = 3
```

If you want inconsistency and since `h(C) <= 3` for the admissibility condition then you should have that `h(A) > 1 + h(C)`. So any heristics that satisfies:

```
h(A) > 1 + h(C)
h(C) <= 3
h(G) = 0
```

is **admissible** and **not consistent**. You gave

```
h(A) = 4
h(C) = 1
h(G) = 0
```

which is a valid candidate.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I am really grateful, now it is clear to me ! :)

Comment: @user3880907 you are welcome, I'm always happy to help :)

Comment: Sorry to bring this up so late but in the list of conditions that are to be satisfied for the heuristic to be admissible and inconsistent, shouldn’t h(A)<=4 also be included ?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a decreasing heuristic function of the depth of the optimal soution path (but attempt to do not violate overestimate condition for admissibility), thereby the result heuristic is admissible but is not consistent.